# Table not rendering properly when I give it a none existant classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

It works fine on IE8 but not on IE9 or the latest Chrome

I suspect it's because I used undefined classnames as a marker to be able to select certain elements. Just like an element's ID. eg: `dnaRow`

class `dnaRow` doesn't actually exist. When I remove `class="dnaRow"` it works again.

```
<TR>
    <TD width="18%">Duration of the Contact</TD>
    <TD width="82%">
        <input tabIndex="4"  type="text" id="contactduration" name="contactduration" class="dataentry blueFont_inset"
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${update}">
                    value='<c:out value="${apptLength}" />'
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${contactInfoMap != null && contactInfoMap['p_actual_appointment_length'] != null}">
                    value="<c:out value="${ contactInfoMap['p_actual_appointment_length']}" />"
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        />
    </TD>
</TR>
    <tr class="dnaRow">
        <td  width="18%" class="dna" >
            DNA$
        </td>
        <td  width="82%" style="float: left; padding-right: 3px; white-space:nowrap"  >
            <div id="dnaDiv">
                <input  tabIndex="5"  id="dnaCheckbox" type="checkbox" >
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: As a test, if you change the name of the class to something totally weird (class="totallyWeirdClassName") does the problem persist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why that should have any affect. But if I were you, I would load up the page in ie9 and press f12, and view the computed style with and without the classname set.  So you can see what style changes exist and you can track the origin of the changes.